# Win 7 won't recognize 850 Evo single disk with HDDs in RAID1

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, raid, raid-1

This has managed to drive me nuts: I used to have 1 SATA HDD as a single drive for OS's and 2 SATA HDDs set-up as RAID1 using the onboard AMD controller for storage, everything was fine. I bought this Samsung 850 Evo SSD, if I switch the onboard controller to AHCI only Win 7 will recognize all drives, including the SSD. If I enable RAID, the BIOS and RAID firmware will correctly recognize all drives, but windows only "sees" the RAID1 array, no SSD. Any ideas?

- Motherboard - Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd. GA-MA785GT-UD3H
- SATA2_0 - Samsung 850 Evo SSD
- SATA2_4, SATA2_5 - AMD 1X2 Mirror/RAID1, bootable, Win7

Comment: Was this a brand new Evo?

Comment: Gawd Gigabye support documents suck, I am willing to bet since raid is enabled you need to provision the drive in the bios raid utility even though it will not be a part of the raid.

Comment: Brand new Evo, and yes the raid firmware has a "raid ready" setting for drives. Did not help. With or without it the ssd does not show up in device manager. Went through 3 diffferent BIOS versions, same story.

Comment: I assume you have tried different sata ports on the motherboard?

Comment: [According to the manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/486809/Gigabyte-Ga-Ma785gt-Ud3h.html?page=78#manual), SATA Port 4 and 5 can be configured differently from the other SATA ports via a setting in the BIOS.  It seems to suggest you should use ports 0-3 for RAID, and then 4 and 5 for your single drive, after adjusting the setting in the BIOS for how those ports work.

Comment: I tried the ssd on ports 2_0 and 2_1, 2_4 and 2_5 can be set to IDE mode.

Comment: It's on port 4 with my dvd on port 5. DVD works fine, SSD still doesn't.